# Ad hoc distribution of my iPad app

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4

I have created an iPad app which I want to send to another branch of my company.  I have .app file which I want to send to him.

Does this colleague have to do anything special other than drop this file into iTunes and install on the device?

Does he need to have a Mac with Xcode any everything or how do I got about this?  I won't have physical address to his device.

EDIT:  This is just a once off thing.  I only want to demo something to him.

Comment: It'd be much easier, much less complicated and much more efficient if you just got him to bring his ipad, plug it into your mac and run it straight from XCode. Otherwise you're going to have to create ad-hoc distribution certificates and all sorts, which gets quite tricky for a one off thing. If you're going to do this kinda thing a lot though, its worth learning. :)

Comment: He is several thousand miles away :)

Comment: are you a paid member of Apple iOS Developer program?

Comment: aha... I take it back then! :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need Xcode or a Mac to install an ad-hoc-provisioned app. All your users need is iTunes.

You need to have your users send you their UUIDs, which you then need to register in Apple's provisioning portal. Download the updated profile and be sure to link to it when building your app for distribution.

I have heard of people having trouble installing .app files. The safest option is to chose "build and archive" from the build menu. This will create an ipa file that can be installed through iTunes. If you open the Xcode organizer after building and archiving, you can select your new ipa and save it to file, or send it by e-mail straight from Xcode.

Comment: I can't comment on Black Frog's post directly, but no, you don't need to belong to the Enterprise program.  http://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/distribute.html

Comment: Hi there I am using Xcode 4 don't seem to see the build and archive menu?

Comment: @TheLearner : Archive is in "Product" menu. After you click Archive, app will appear in organizer.

Comment: @Jean-Marc - I have managed to get to the point of 'sharing the app' and creating the ipa file.  However when I drag it into iTunes I get the following error:  The app "…" was not installed on the iPad "My iPad" because the entitlements are not valid.

Comment: @TheLearner did you make sure to register the iPad's UUID with Apple? Did you also drag the .mobileprovision into iTunes along with the .ipa file?

Comment: This is no valid answer. Entitlements issues can arise independently from the user installing .app+certificate or .ipa using the archiving tool.

Answer (score 4):

This article looks really good as far as basic setup goes - http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/35818-unofficial-ad-hoc-distribution-guide.html

After that, you just need to send out the .app and the .mobileprovision. Both the files need to be dragged into iTunes. Check if Sync apps is enabled and that your app is selected. Hit sync and it should work.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to belong to [iOS Developer Enterprise Program](http://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/).

Comment: No, like the poster above says, iOS enterprise program isn't a requirement. Normal accounts work for sending out your app to 100 beta testers.

Comment: If you notice the time I responded to his question, he edited his question to include "...once off thing."